# Error: Econnrefured when connect to localhost

Tags: proxy, localhost, postman

Hi I'm new to postman and I have this problem connecting to local host.
I made a POST request to localhost:3000 and it keeps showing error: connect econnrefuse 127.0.0.1:3000.
I have tried to check and uncheck the Use the system proxy and also add a custom proxy.
It still doesn't work.
Could someone please help me? Thanks

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmIuj.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUUGM.png)

[postman proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wysN.png)

Comment: it means that no service is running in that port

Comment: did you made sure its running

Comment: It runs on my terminal, that's why I think it's because of proxy

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your postman proxy settings and system proxy settings , are you able to access localhost in de browser after disabling proxy

Comment: I put the screenshot in the post, thanks

Comment: remove proxy also addyour postman request the method the endpoint url etc you used , also put screen shot showing the service is running and is able to open in browser